# Asp.NET: How to install CoolControls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-controls

I cannot seem to install this [control](http://ideasparks.codeplex.com/). I use Visual Studi 2012, I downloaded the dll. I put it in my project folder, I added a reference of it, and I added this line to my aspx site:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="IdeaSparx.CoolControls.Web" Namespace="IdeaSparx.CoolControls.Web" TagPrefix="cc" %>
```

In my aspx site, I add the control:

```
    <cc:CoolGridView ID="CoolGridView1" runat="server" Height="400px" Width="600px">
 </cc:CoolGridView>
```

But when I add a control, it says there was an error rendering this control. What can be the problem?

Comment: What's the actual error?

Comment: When I add the control and switch to design view, there is no control and it says "There was an error rendering this control. Object reference not set to an instance of object." When I start the page, there is only an empty rectangle, where the control is supposed to be.

Comment: Can you show where and how you "add a control"?

Comment: I updated my question, there it is.

Comment: Okay I found the problem, it was my fault, I had to connect it to a datasource.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the problem, it was my fault, I had to connect it to a datasource and it works.